# Is it possible to appending the new results to existing result window?

Tags: vim, cscope

Once vim cscope search finishes, vim opens a new quickfix window to show result. Is it possible to appending the new results to existing result windows instead of opening a new quickfix window? 
(Source Insight supports this way, BTW)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to check the `:help cs`. You can find the following variable to activate (or not) the quickfix window :

> 'cscopequickfix' specifies whether to use quickfix window to show
>   cscope results.  This is a list of comma-separated values. Each item
>   consists of cscope-find command (s, g, d, c, t, e, f, i or a) and flag
>   (+, - or 0). '+' indicates that results must be appended to quickfix
>   window, '-' implies previous results clearance, '0' or command absence
>   - don't use quickfix.  Search is performed from start until first command occurrence. The default value is "" (don't use quickfix
>   anyway).  The following value seems to be useful:
>           :set cscopequickfix=s-,c-,d-,i-,t-,e-,a-

Comment: kk9527, did you manage to find a good setup to mimic Source Insight's relation window? I'm thinking about learning Vimscript just to port it. I'm used to the tree view of references, something mixing cscope search and NERDtree would be awesome.

Comment: then let me suggest you [this website](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/). He made a step-by-step tutorial about vim, it's way of work and viml, and specifically the good practices and the way to design modules.